# How to set animated theme on login screen in Mint 18.3 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, theme

I found the tutorial how to set animated theme on login screen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-w7Aw5p6zbY. Unfortunately cannot set it in my local installation. I use Mint 18.3. Below is my login window configuration applet which looks different than the one from the tutorial.

[image]

Is that option still available? If yes, where can I find it or what should I do to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that since Mint 18.2 there is LightDM display manager (instead of MDM) which simply does not support that feature.